# PHP Crawl Specific Tab Content of External Website & Return href

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, file-get-contents

Using PHP, I want to retrieve a specific element in an external website.

The external website is https://mcnmedia.tv/iframe/2684 The specific element I want to retrieve is the **first link** in the 'Recordings' tab.

For example, the first link contains the following html;

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 me column recording-item">
    <div class="recording-item-inner">
        <a class="small-12 column recording-name" href="/recordings/2435">
        <div class="info">
            <b>Mass</b><br>
            <small>26 Mar 2020</small>
        </div><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the `href` and display a direct link on my website like;

`View Latest Recording - https://mcnmedia.tv/recordings/2435`.

I have the following PHP but it isn't working as i'd like, currently it outputs the text only (`Mass 26 Mar 2020`), I'm not sure how to get the actual `href` link address?

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('https://mcnmedia.tv/iframe/2684');
@$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($page);   
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='recording-item-inner']");
$node = $nodeList->item(0);
// To check the result:
echo "<p>" . $node->nodeValue . "</p>";
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going quite far enough with your XPath to fetch the href, you can add `/a/@href` to say use the `href` attribute inside the `<a>` tag...

```
$nodeList = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@class='recording-item-inner']/a/@href");
```

you can simplify this, use `evaluate()` to fetch a specific value and modify the XPath to be fetch the attribute as a string instead of the node...

```
$href = $xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='recording-item-inner']/a/@href)");
echo "<p>" . $href . "</p>";
```